# Remove unwanted vertical space before and after math (and other) environments in tabular cells

Tags: tables, math-mode, spacing, nicematrix

I want to remove vertical space before and after math and other environments like `description`, so they look tight and with even space at the top and bottom like Row 1.

[image]

As you can see, I already test commands like `\belowdisplayskip` without success.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

% Not works.
%\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
%\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
%\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
%\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}    

\begin{tabular}{m{3cm} m{3cm}}
    \hline
    Row 1 & Text \\ \hline
    Row 2 &
        \begin{description}[topsep=0pt]
            \item[$\alpha$] Alpha
            \item[$\beta$] Beta
        \end{description} \\ \hline
    Row 3 &
        \begin{equation*}
            E = mc^2
        \end{equation*} \\ \hline
    Row 4 &
        \begin{equation*}
            \sum_i x_i
        \end{equation*}  \\ \hline
    Row 5 &
        {\begin{align*}
              y &= ax^2 + bx \\
              &= x(ax + b)
        \end{align*}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: These environments will certainly add the space like this including `equation*` and `center`. From the academic perspective, just use the inline mode like `$E=mc^2$`.

Comment: Thanks but I also use environments like `align`, so I still need a solution.

Comment: You can use `$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$` which will not treat the math like a display.  (See the `amsmath` user guide, `texdoc amsldoc`.)

Answer (score 6):

- For math equations you can use any of `amsmath` math environments:  `aligned`, `gathered` and `split`
- With `tabular` the result is not very nice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}| m{5cm}|}
    \hline
    Row 1 &     Text            \\ \hline
    Row 2 &     Text            \\ \hline
    Row 3 & $E = mc^2$          \\ \hline
    Row 4 & $\sum_i x_i$        \\ \hline
    Row 4 & $\begin{aligned}
             \sin(x) & = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \cdots \\
                     & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}\\[1ex]
             \end{aligned}$     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

With use `tabularray` the result is much better:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[htb]    
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l,m, 3cm]  Q[l,m, mode=math]},
             row{1,2}= {mode=text},
             rowsep=3pt
             }
    Row 1 &     Text            \\  
    Row 2 &     Text            \\  
    Row 3 & E = mc^2            \\  
    Row 4 & \sum_i x_i          \\  
    Row 4 & \begin{aligned}
             \sin(x) & = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \cdots \\
                     & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}\\[1ex]
             \end{aligned}     \\  
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the second example is assumed that in the second column are with exception it the first two rows, equation. Therefore this column is in math mode.

If you like to have for some reasons contents in the second column centered, than `Q[l,m, mode=math]` replace with `Q[c,m, mode=math]`. This change will gives:

[image]

Comment: Just a minor detail. Shouldn't the first column be `Q` type as well? A `X` column makes no sense with a specified width.

Comment: @marv, you are right. Corrected now.

Comment: I was wondering why it still worked. The package author stated in [this issue](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/100) that an `X` column will be ignored, if a `wd` is specified.

Comment: @marv My bad. I should have said that  `co` option would be ignored, but not the column itself.

Comment: @Zarko Ok, maybe `center` environment wasn't a good choice for what I require, so I edited my question with other more appropriate evironment.

I like the `tabularray` solution but it seems not correct the problem at all in `aligned`-like envs., there's more espace below than at the top, I don't know the reason but since I use those envs. a lot I can't accept the answer yet.

Answer (score 4):

You can try another flavor using `nicematrix`. Does not add any space to the natural height of the cells. (first table).

Usually one wants to expand cells to avoid collision of the rules with subscripts and superscripts.

By using `cell-space-limits=` you can add some space above and below the content (1pt, second table).

Finally it is possible to improve only the superscripts
using `cell-space-top-limit=1pt` (last table).

**Default**

[image: d]

**Better**

[image: e]

[image: f]

This is the complete code.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[htb] 
    \centering
    \caption{Default: tight}  
        \begin{NiceTabular}{lc}[hvlines]
            Row 1   &     Text            \\  
            Row 2   &     Text            \\  
            Row 3   & $E = mc^2$          \\  
            Row 4   & $\sum_i x_i$         \\  
            Row 5   & $\begin{aligned}
                            \sin(x) & = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \cdots \\
                                    & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}\\
                        \end{aligned} $    \\  
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb] 
    \centering
    \caption{More relaxed (added 1pt)}      
    \begin{NiceTabular}{lc}[hvlines,  cell-space-limits=1pt] % expand upper and lower space
    Row 1   &     Text            \\  
        Row 2   &     Text            \\  
        Row 3   & $E = mc^2$          \\  
        Row 4   & $\sum_i x_i$         \\  
        Row 5   & $\begin{aligned}
                        \sin(x) & = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \cdots \\
                                & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}\\
        \end{aligned} $    \\  
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb] 
    \centering
    \caption{Semi relaxed (added above 1pt)}    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{lc}[hvlines,   cell-space-top-limit=1pt] % expand only lower space
        Row 1   &     Text            \\  
        Row 2   &     Text            \\  
        Row 3   & $E = mc^2$          \\  
        Row 4   & $\sum_i x_i$         \\  
        Row 5   & $\begin{aligned}
            \sin(x) & = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \cdots \\
            & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}\\
        \end{aligned} $    \\  
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

1. With the package nicematrix.  If you want a environment equation, i think it's necessary to use minipage
2. with the code of Simon Dispa

   ```
        Row 4 & \begin{minipage}{5cm}\begin{equation*}
                \sum_i x_i
            \end{equation*} \end{minipage}\\
   ```

[image]